# how to access kaggle data after downloading with terminal?

Tags: python, machine-learning, kaggle

I have downloaded the data using

```
kaggle competitions download -c pubg-finish-placement-prediction
```

but I am confused on how to access it in my python scripts that I would be creating ?

Comment: Please use other tags than `kaggle` next time, something that brings a little more attention to your problem (don't overuse it though). `python` and `machine-learning` would be perfectly fine and you would get your answer immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This command downloads data to the localization you are currently in within your terminal. It display what's been downloaded + you can check it using linux's `ls` command. You should see those three files if properly configured:

```
train_V2.csv
test_V2.csv 
sample_submission_V2.csv
```

(you can find description of each on the competition's site [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/pubg-finish-placement-prediction/data).

Data can be loaded using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library, this code will display the contents of one of the `.csv` files:

```
df = pd.read_csv("train_V2.csv")
print(df.head())
```

BTW. this competition is [kernel only](https://www.kaggle.com/c/movie-review-sentiment-analysis-kernels-only/discussion/64739) so you cannot make a submission using this data from your localhost.